# I want to call an Azure Face API more then once in a loop and save all results in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops-rest-api

I am calling a Face API and a image to that API and getting the results in Json. I want to call this api more then once in a loop and  save all results for all images in a loop in an array. Unfortunately i cannot do it.

```
        foreach (var allwords in ViewBag.sentence)
        {
            string imgpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") + allwords + ".png";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters = "&returnFaceAttributes=smile," +
                "emotion";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
            byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imgpath);

            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
                // The other content types you can use are "application/json"
                // and "multipart/form-data".
                content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Execute the REST API call.
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                // Get the JSON response.
                string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contentString);
                //array to store every image result
                string results = contentString;

              // return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
```

I am getting only one image result, which is the last image the web api called. I am calling all images in a loop but i couldn't save the results of images which it called before the last image.

Comment: You are not adding adding images to array in the code... You need to write that code. What's the issue you are facing in that?

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, i cant add images response which is in 'contentString' to an array. it gives the error of type that i cant put string into an array. Need that code to add all images response to an array

Comment: Can you add the code which tries to add to the array? In the current code there is no array used. The simple approach would be create a string array or list of string and add contentString to it.

Comment: i tried it before, it gives this error ...                                                                        string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contentString);
                    //array to store every image result
                    string[] arr = contentString; ;

Comment: Cannot implicitly  convert type 'string'  to 'string[]', this is the error

Comment: You need to do `var images = new List<string>();` before foreach loop and instead of `string[] arr = contentString;` you should to `images.Add(contentString);`

Comment: You are life saver!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: can you tell me a little bit that how can i print these results? from images

Comment: @RajaAliKhan How do you want to print results?